# Search for words from two lists in a sentence

Tags: python, string

I have two lists containing unique words, I want to search if a particular sentence has any of the words from either of the lists.

Based on their presence I will classify the text into two categories, list 1, list 2 or neither. I have written this code into problem, but the code does not reach the second if-statement. Could you please help me rectify this.

```py
def word_in_text(word, text):
    word = word.lower()
    text = str(text)
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
    return False    


def builder(teams_playing, feature, text):
    for feat in feature[teams_playing[0]]:
        if word_in_text(feat, text):
            return teams_playing[0]
        else:
            continue
    for feat in feature[teams_playing[1]]:
        if word_in_text(feat, text):
            return teams_playing[1]
        else:
            continue
    return 'ambiguous'
```

In the above code, `teams_playing[0]` and `teams_playing[1]` are strings (essentially the class I want to classify the text into) and feature is a dict that has features of the two classes and `feature[teams_playing[0]]` and `feature[teams_playing[1]]` are list containing unique strings.

Comment: In the function definition you specify a parameter called `features`, in the function itself you refer to a variable called `feature`.  Is this intentional?

Comment: What if a sentence contains words from both lists of words? How is it categorized?

Comment: I am sorry, the function parameter should be feature

Comment: I know for a fact that the sentence has words from only one list or neither of the lists.

Comment: Why are you converting the string text into a string? `text = str(text)`.  If indeed text is a string this doesn't do anything harmful, but it is confusing.

Comment: Do you care that re.search is going to match partial strings, so that "apple" will be found in "apples".

Comment: @BradBudlong, that was added because that function is used on other  inputs as well and is not restricted to just this. It also processes pandas objects, so I needed to put this in there to stop the errors.

Comment: @BradBudlong No apple/apples does not matter, could you please elaborate, I am not too familiar with the re library.

Comment: You are using a regular expression search which when given just a word will return an object if it finds it anywhere and None if not.  This is overkill and it also has the problem that if the feat has any special characters in it, then it is going to do some unexpected things.  If this is really searching for a word in a set of text then `match = word in text` would be more appropriate.

Comment: The text can contain hashtags or the '@' symbol, will that be a problem??

Comment: What does it mean that it never gets to the second if statement.  Do you mean that it always returns team_playing[0] or that it gets stuck in the first for loop.

Comment: Yeah, the entire output was just the team_playing[0]

Comment: @NitinKashyap you say you use `text = str(text)` because "that function . . . also processes `pandas` objects . . ."  are you saying `text` is occasionally a `pandas` object (i'm assuming you mean `DataFrame`)?  you convert `DataFrame`s to strings?

Comment: @dbliss I use it when I want a particular entry in a DataFrame to be converted into a string, not the entire DataFrame. For this instance, you can just ignore the str(text) line though.

Comment: @BradBudlong, i tried it with `match = word in text`, made no difference at all. I think the problem is with how the loop and the ifs and not in the `word_in_text` function.

Comment: Maybe if you could give example of the contents of `teams_playing`, `feature` and `text` it'd be easier to debug?

Comment: ^ yes, knowing how you're defining these variables is crucial

Comment: `teams_playing[0] = 'Liverpool'`

`teams_playing[1] = 'Man Utd'`

`feature[teams_playing[0]] = ['#YNWA', '#lfc', '@LFC', 'Liverpool']`

`feature[teams_playing[1]] = ['Manchester', 'United', 'Man', 'Utd', '@ManUtd', '', '#mufc']`

an example of text is: 'Dad of three, all views are my own, Liverpool Season Ticket Holder & all round football fan #YNWA'

Comment: With this example, since #YNWA is in the text and also in first list, the builder() function will return 'Liverpool' and never get to the second for loop.  So you still haven't shown a problem.  Please remove the "else: continue" statements at the end of each loop, they don't do anything.

Comment: Yeah it works in this case, but it shows, Liverpool for cases when there are keywords from the other team as well.